# Subtract values only if all are numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to subtract four cells in excel from one specific cell but only if any of the four cells have a value. More specifically in my case the formula in cell L2 is currently

`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E2),ISNUMBER(G2),ISNUMBER(I2),ISNUMBER(K2),),"",D2-E2-G2-I2-K2)`

but I only want this to be calculated when any or all of cells E2,G2,I2,K2 has a value. What am I missing in the formula to make L2 return a 0 unlessthe above is true?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  (1) As you’ve noticed, questions on Super User allow for “tags” to indicate the general subject area.  Titles are meant to be used for a summary of the specific question.  Although “Computing a formula conditionally” wouldn’t have been a great title, it would have been better than “Microsoft Excel 2010”.  (2) What’s in `E2`, `G2`, `I2`, and `K2` if not numbers?  Blanks?  If you want the subtraction to be calculated if any or all of the cells has a value, use `OR` instead of `AND`.  (Also make [the changes teylyn suggested](http://superuser.com/a/921706/150988).)

Comment: Yes Scott the cells would be blank if no numeric value is entered. Also the "stray comma" is the only way the original formula will work if a number is entered into (K2). Without that comma the cell (L2) will be blank and not calculate anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do — and what we should have asked you to do two days ago —
is to give some examples of what results you want for what inputs. 
Yes, I know you’ve given us a few,
but they should have been [edited](https://superuser.com/posts/921627/edit) into the question;
comments are a lousy place for tabular data and long formulas,
and they are the *wrong* place for information
that’s necessary to understand the question. 
Anyway, I’ve created some sample data for you. 
Note that they are not all correct. 
I know they’re not all correct, because they are inconsistent,
but also I would have trouble making them all correct because I’m still struggling to understand what you want.

```
        Case       D        E        G        I        K        L (Result)
        fee       40        1                                  39
        fie       40        0.01                               39.99
        foe       40        0                                  40
        fum       40                                           40
        foo       40                                            0
```

If cases `fee` and `fie` don’t reflect what you want,
we’ve got a serious communication problem. 
If you will never, ever, in a gazillion years
have an actual **`0`** in `E2`, `G2`, `I2`, or `K2`,
then we don’t really need to worry about case `foe`. 
So, the $40,000 question is: do you want `fum` (`L2` = 40) or `foo` (`L2` = 0)?

#### `fum` (`L2` = 40)

This is simple.  Set `L2` to any of the following,

- `=D2-E2-G2-I2-K2`
- `=D2-(E2+G2+I2+K2)`
- `=D2-SUM(E2,G2,I2,K2)`

which are equivalent.

#### `foo` (`L2` = 0)

A bit longer, but just as obvious:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(E2),ISNUMBER(G2),ISNUMBER(I2),ISNUMBER(K2)), D2-E2-G2-I2-K2, 0)
```

This may look familiar, as it is Teylyn’s answer combined with my comment
(“If you want the subtraction to be calculated if any or all of cells has a value, … use `OR` instead of `AND`.”)

#### Huh?  What?

Your original formula,

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E2),ISNUMBER(G2),ISNUMBER(I2),ISNUMBER(K2),),"",D2-E2-G2-I2-K2)
```

is (as Teylyn pointed out) calling the `AND()` function with five parameters:

- `ISNUMBER(E2)`,
- `ISNUMBER(G2)`,
- `ISNUMBER(I2)`,
- `ISNUMBER(K2)`, and
- (blank).

Well, if a blank value is used as a number in Excel,
it is treated as if it were 0 (zero).  That’s why the “`fum`” formulas work:
the cells that are blank are treated as if they contained 0. 
Likewise, if a blank value is used as a Boolean (i.e., logical value) in Excel,
it is treated as if it were FALSE.  So your formula acts like

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E2),ISNUMBER(G2),ISNUMBER(I2),ISNUMBER(K2),FALSE),"",D2-E2-G2-I2-K2)
```

Since `AND(anything, FALSE)` is `FALSE`, the above reduces to

```
=IF(FALSE, "", D2-E2-G2-I2-K2)
```

or simply

```
=D2-E2-G2-I2-K2
```

This may look familiar, as it is the “`fum`” formula.

---

#### Are we there yet?

If I’ve missed some arcane aspect of your question,
please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/921627/edit) to clarify it;
e.g., add sample data where neither of the above answers
gives the results you want.

Comment: The "foo (L2=0) formula posted above is the correct formula I was looking for. I am sorry for the confusion and lack of a good beginning question. But thank you. this will help a great deal in my material tracking issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula returns an empty string when all conditions are met. I think you want the calculation in that place. There is a stray comma in the AND() function.

According to your verbal description, the formula you probably need is

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E2),ISNUMBER(G2),ISNUMBER(I2),ISNUMBER(K2)),D2-E2-G2-I2-K2,0)
```

This will only do the calculation if all cells contain a value.

> but I only want this to be calculated when any or all of cells E2,G2,I2,K2 has a value.

You need to make up your mind. If you want to do the calculation when any cell contains a value, you don't need an IF statement. In that case, just do the subtraction.

Comment: Teylyn's correct.  Excel will treat all blank and non-numeric cells as zero.  You could also use "=D2-(SUM(E2,G2,I2,K2))".

Comment: It occurred to me last night after I wrote that and turned off my computer that if you're cells are the result of a calculation and an Excel error value is possible (i.e. #/DIV/0, #/N/A, etc.), then you would want to use ISNUMBER as in my example in the other answer.

Comment: I am trying to use the formula to calculate pipe loss, but only if the length changes.  If the original length is 40(D2) and cut is made on it 10(E2), then an additional cut is made 10(G2) and no others cuts were made(I2)&(K2) would be blank, then value of 20 would be in (L2). Then on a different piece of pipe the original length 45(D2) an no cuts were made so (E2,G2,I2,K2) would be blank. I need the (L2) to return 0 not the number 45(D2).  Better explanation?or example rather

Comment: Okay.  Then this works:
=IF(SUM(E2,G2,I2,K2)=0,0,D2-IF(ISNUMBER(E2),E2,0)-IF(ISNUMBER(G2),G2,0)-IF(ISNUMBER(I2),I2,0)-IF(ISNUMBER(K2),K2,0))

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you might need a helper row. You could put it right under the cells in question using the formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E2),E2,0)
```

.  Then you could just do simple subtraction on the helper row.  Of course, that formula would be entered in E3.  And BTW, an AND statement is true only if all of its arguments are true, so your formula would only work when all of the cells in it contained numbers.  If only one cell contained a non-numeric value, the formula would evaluate to false and not calculate.  FWIW False = 0; True = Not False.

Comment: The formula does return the desired value even if the cells do not contain a number. If the following numbers are used as example 40(D2)10(E2)5(G2) and no entry in cells I and/or K excel would calculate the cell(L2) to have a value of 25. The same is true if the cells have nothing entered it will return whatever the valve of D2 is. In the case of the example it would return 40.

Comment: Here's another alternative that doesn't involve using a helper row:

=D2-IF(ISNUMBER(E2),E2,0)-IF(ISNUMBER(G2),G2,0)-IF(ISNUMBER(I2),I2,0)-IF(ISNUMBER(K2),K2,0)

Comment: The formula above returns #NAME? when entered into my spreadsheet

Comment: Wade, strange...I got that too when I pasted that formula from this site into a spreadsheet.  There seems to be a problem with the last ISNUMBER expression.  Just backspace over it and retype it.  I'd backspace all the way to the minus sign.